# understanding a notation in printf

Tags: c

This might be a very basic question to many of you, but I am not able to understand 
what %.*s doing?

```
void substring(int i, int j, char *ch) 
{
      printf("The substring is: %.*s\n", j - i, &ch[i]); 
      //what is %.*s doing?
}
```

Comment: `.*` *The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.* See [printf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: basic questions can definitely be asked , the only thing is before asking , you should have done some mimimum from your side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` is taking the length limit for the string from the argument before the string.  So the printf will output (at most) `j - i` characters from `&ch[i]` to `stdout`.  If the string is shorter, then the entire string will be printed, but it will not be blank padded.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good reference for `printf`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf.<sup>*</sup>

And this is what it says:

> `.` followed by integer number or `*` that specifies precision of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type `int`. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. See the table below for exact effects of precision.

And for `s`, it says:

> Precision specifies the maximum number of bytes to be written.

So in your case, it prints a maximum of `j-i` characters.

---

<sub>* In fact, it's a very good reference for just about all standard C and C++ libraries.  Use it!</sub>